# Структура проекта сайт на React + админ панель + NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

Как правильно организовать проект в котором будет сам сайт на React 
+ будет панель администратора тоже на React 
NodeJS будет в качестве бєкенда

Какая будет правильная струкутра,

1. панель администратора мне положить в папку с сайтом в src (в create
   react app) и сделать ее просто отдельным модулем в папке с основным
   сайтом допустим папка admin?
2. сделать отдельным проектом создать новый create react app? только для админки

---

если выбрать пункт 2 то как мне потом все залить на хостинг?
 в конце работы у меня будет 2 папки build (то есть сам сайт + админ панель) и server на NodeJS

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел решение и сам отвечу на свой вопрос, может кому-то пригодится...

```
/* Админ панель */

app.use('/admin/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'admin')))
app.get('/admin/*', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'admin', 'index.html'));
});

/* Сам сайт */

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'front-end')))
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'front-end', 'index.html'));
});
```